# If my text length is big in li div, then div span and li height auto adjust..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

This is my li tag.

I want make it auto adjust li,span and div tag Heights, if text length is big in left and right div tag.
I want put left and right div width=50%

I want this type of li if text length is big in left and right div, there is screeshot below

Thanks In Advance.

```html
<li style="height:35px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">
  <span style="height:35px;display:flex;">
      <div style="position:absolute;float:right;right:10px;margin-top:8px;" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">Ariana Grande Is Looking Beautifull</div>
      <div style="display:none;">2</div>
      <div style="position:absolute;float:left;left:10px;margin-top:8px;" class="garshuninamefont">Justin Biber Selena Gomez</div>
  </span>
</li>
```

[image: I want This Type Of Li when Text Length Is big]

Comment: put `height:auto;`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I Use it but it makes my design inproper

Comment: what type of design you want?without knowing your desired output how can wee>

Comment: why absolute ? if you set ul in absolute, then no need for the rest to  be absolute.

Comment: If you have `position: absolute`, float isn't going to do anything

Comment: @AlivetoDie please see my image i want this type of li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure why `flex` + `float` + `absolute` + `height`.

**For `flex`**, *`float`, `height` and `absolute` could be dropped:*

```html
<li style="height:35px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">
    <span style="height:35px;display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
    <div style="font-family:SertoJerusalem;margin:8px 10px;" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">Ariana Grande Is Looking Beautifull</div>
    <div style="display:none;">2</div>
    <div style="margin:8px 10px;" class="garshuninamefont">Justin Biber Selena Gomez</div>
  </span>
</li><li style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">
    <span style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;">
    <div style="font-family:SertoJerusalem;margin:8px 10px;" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">Ariana Grande Is Looking Beautifull</div>
    <div style="display:none;">2</div>
    <div style="margin:8px 10px;" class="garshuninamefont">Justin Biber <br/>Selena Gomez</div>
  </span>
</li>
```

This might be usefull to read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

Removed `height: 35px;` for `li`.

```html
<li style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">
  <span style="height:35px;display:flex;">
        <div style="float:right;margin-top:8px;width: 50%;font-family:SertoJerusalem;" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">Ariana Grande Is Looking Beautifull</div>
        <div style="display:none;">2</div>
        <div style="float:left;width: 50%;margin-top:8px;" class="garshuninamefont">Justin Biber Selena Gomez</div>
      </span>
</li>
```